# Show content depending on domain using jQuery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, subdomain, business-catalyst

HI Guys I have a site that carries 2 domains one is **.com** and the other is a **.us** I am trying to get it to show a flag for the country domain chosen so if it is clicked on a link to direct to a .us I wanted to show the US flag:

I have made this so far but sometimes it works but sometimes not I have no idea why!

HTML:

```
<li>Currency <img class="usd-flag" style="display:none" src="/images/usd-flag.svg" width="20" height="14" alt="USD CURRENCY $;"/><img class="gbp-flag" style="display:none" src="/images/gbp-flag.svg" width="20" height="14" alt="GBP CURRENCY &pound;"/>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com">BRITISH POUNDS ( &pound; ) </a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.us">US DOLLARS ( $ )</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
if(location.href.indexOf('.us') >= 0) {
        $('.usd-flag').show();
        $('.gbp-flag').hide();
    }
if(location.href.indexOf('.com') >= 0) {
        $('.gbp-flag').show();
        $('.usd-flag').hide();
    }//changes flag image depending on domain
```

Can some one tells me whats wrong here plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with  a liquid if else statement and use contain.

```
{% if {{globals.site.host}} contains '.us' %}

<div>this is a .us domain</div>

{% else %} 

<div>This is a .com domain</div>

{% endif %}
```

OR you could use 2 if Statements as well. rather than the else depending on what you need.

Temporary Example here using AU domain.

http://liquiddev.rtweb.com.au/domain

Hope it helps!

Comment: I must say the liquid one is the best for BC's Reason, but the jQuery option is also good perhaps for a different server and had a few errors with server request.

Answer (score 1):

Well of the top of my head I would recommend [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) instead of location.href as it has a better output for parsing, but I think you just forgot the need to wait for the DOM to by ready before modifying it's elements. As you have tagged with `jQuery` you can use the below. Without it you will need a document event handler (which `jQuery` just wraps for you).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    console.log(location.href)
    console.log(document.domain)

    if (location.href.indexOf('.us') >= 0) {
        $('.usd-flag').show();
        $('.gbp-flag').hide();
    }
    if (location.href.indexOf('.com') >= 0) {
        $('.gbp-flag').show();
        $('.usd-flag').hide();
    } //changes flag image depending on domain

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2pfmdp4f/)

Comment: Worked well I have still some issues when it comes to have a HTTPS page but that'd be my server that messes up the situation. thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can change location.href.indexOf to location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf first, so it will support url as .COM